# Mobile phone screen orientation always in landscape with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

How to make the view on mobile phone always in landscape orientation with Bootstrap? Is it possible?

I have done this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to force the user to hold their phone sideways? This might make some people really angry...